# mkdir not working, only with mkdir -p in rootserver with plesk

Tags: ubuntu, mkdir, plesk

I just ordered a new root server 18.04 Ubuntu with Plesk.
I log in as root and want to create a folder for example:

```
mkdir /usr/local/myfolder/hello
```

I get the error:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/myfolder/hello’: No such file or directory
```

It only works, when I use `mkdir -p`.
I can only create 1 folder ahead, when I am in the directory, not a path.

For me this is not normal, how can I fix this? Also my scripts dont run because of this.

Thanks

Comment: `alias mkdir='mkdir -p'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mkdir` only creates one single directory when called without `-p`.

A directory in the path `/usr/local/myfolder/` is missing, this is why you get the error. If you call `mkdir -p`, the missing path is created as well.

Another effect of using the `-p` option is that `mkdir -p` does not complain when the directory already exists. This is why this variant is frequently used in scripts.

Comment: Thanks the reason why I ask this. Is because I want to install antmedia server using the create_app.sh and it says mkdir cannot create path even as root! Then if I manually create it, it says file already exists abort. This never happened to me.

Comment: @zer02 since `mkdir -p` does not complain when the target directory already exists, it is frequently used from inside shell scripts.